# Passing arraylist of objects from Java to PHP via Apache HTTPClient

Tags: java, php, arraylist, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a java program that passes data to a php webservice via apache httpclient. Currently all it is passing is user authentication details and a string variable. These are received and handled fine on the PHP side. I would also like to pass an ArrayList of objects in a way that I can read the object attributes from PHP. Is there a way to do this directly in the same way I'm passing parameters or do I need to use JSON objects or something else? The objects contained have 4 attributes, not just name value pairs.

My Java code looks like so:

```
    public void upload(ArrayList<MyObject> myList) throws Exception{

    //HTTP POST Service
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();         
        URI uri = new URIBuilder()
        .setScheme("http")
        .setHost("www.mysite.com")
        .setPath("/webservice.php")
        .build();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("var1", var1));

        String encoding = new String(
                 org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64   
                    (org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(userID + ":" + password))
                  );
        httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        System.out.println(response);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        String str = "";
        if (httpEntity != null) {
            str = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

My use case for this is basically that I want to update a MySQL database table on my server with each attribute of my java object being the value of one field (i.e. one object = one table row). So I want to be able to pass my ArrayList such that I can add multiple rows to my database table in one go.

EDIT2. Okay I now have the following method to construct my JSONArray where the variables passed were previously the attributes of my object. The JSON objects are now what would previously have been my object, and the jsonArray is what would previously have been my ArrayList. Is this correct? How can I post it from my httpclient?

```
     public void constructJSON(long var1, int var2, int var3, int var4){

    JSONObject obj;
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    try {
        obj = new JSONObject();
                    obj.put("var1:", var1);
        obj.put("var2:", var2);
        obj.put("var3:", var3);
        obj.put("var4:", var4);
        jsonArray.put(obj);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I think POSTing JSON is a reasonable solution.

Comment: You posted your Java code, but is this really a PHP question? That is do you want to know how to decode JSON in PHP, or encode JSON with Java? Or are you asking if there is some better Object encoding strategy? Like maybe caucho quercus (which would give you JMS in PHP)?

Comment: Primarily I'm asking, is it possible to pass the object easily without further encoding and if not then what is the best way to pass such an ArrayList from one to the other? If consensus if that JSON is the best way to do so then any pointers of how to encode an ArrayList as a JSON object would also be very helpful.

Comment: Using quercus might be the best. I don't know your use case very well.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it. I've also updated the question to make my use case clearer.

Comment: Where is your `ArrayList`, and can you not call MySQL through JDBC (Statement has [addBatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch%28java.lang.String%29))?

Comment: My ArrayList is being passed as the parameter to the method posted above. I thought about using JDBC directly first but my hosting service doesn't provide remote access to the database (since it's a shared server) without specifying the IPs (which isn't useful for me). Other questions on here led me to believe using an intermediate webservice was the best practice general solution?

Comment: Use [JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) and [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html). Quercus is not really appropriate, and there are certainly other strategies you can use. But JSON seems reasonable.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how the JSONArray and JSONObject correspond to Java Arrays and Objects. I've edited my question to show what I've tried but I'm not sure my understanding of the concept is correct.